# How can i generate function call tree in IDA & proper disassembly from obsucated flow?

Tags: ida

I'm trying to properly disassembly the following code in IDA but failing to do that because code flow is obfuscated with `call / jnz byte ptr [eax-2]` how is it supposed to look like for IDA?

```
.text:3005AE20                                         public expoted_function_entry
.text:3005AE20                         expoted_function_entry:
.text:3005AE20 53                                      push    ebx
.text:3005AE21 83 EC 18                                sub     esp, 18h
.text:3005AE24 8B 44 24 20                             mov     eax, [esp+20h]
.text:3005AE28 A3 84 64 08 30                          mov     ds:dword_30086484, eax
.text:3005AE2D E8 01 00 00 00                          call    loc_3005AE33
.text:3005AE2D                         ; ----------------------------------------------    
.text:3005AE32 68                      byte_3005AE32   db 68h                  ; CODE     XREF: .text:3005AE3E↓j
.text:3005AE33                         ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:3005AE33
.text:3005AE33                         loc_3005AE33:                           ; CODE XREF: .text:3005AE2D↑j
.text:3005AE33 58                                      pop     eax
.text:3005AE34 85 C0                                   test    eax, eax
.text:3005AE36 74 10                                   jz      short locret_3005AE48
.text:3005AE38 0F B6 40 FE                             movzx   eax, byte ptr [eax-2]
.text:3005AE3C 85 C0                                   test    eax, eax
.text:3005AE3E 75 F2                                   jnz     short near ptr byte_3005AE32
.text:3005AE40 8D 05 4A AE 05 30                       lea     eax, word_3005AE4A
.text:3005AE46 FF E0                                   jmp     eax
.text:3005AE48                         ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:3005AE48
.text:3005AE48                         locret_3005AE48:                        ; CODE XREF: .text:3005AE36↑j
.text:3005AE48 C9                                      leave
.text:3005AE49 C3                                      retn
.text:3005AE49                         ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:3005AE4A E8 01                   word_3005AE4A   dw 1E8h                 ; DATA XREF: .text:3005AE40↑o
.text:3005AE4C 00 00 00 BF 8B 1C 24 58+                dd 0BF000000h, 58241C8Bh, 850C7443h, 8DF474C0h
.text:3005AE5C                         ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:3005AE5C 1D 64 AE 05 30                          sbb     eax, (offset loc_3005AE63+1)
.text:3005AE61 FF E3                                   jmp     ebx
.text:3005AE63                         ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```